# Writing a vim function to insert a block of static text

Tags: function, vim

I'd like to be able to do something like this in vim (you can assume v7+ if it helps).

Type in a command like this (or something close)

```
:inshtml
```

and have vim dump the following into the current file at the current cursor location

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can I write a vim function do this is?  Is there a better way?

Comment: Look at the UltiSnips plugin: https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips.

Comment: If you'd like a certain template or format every time you open a new file of a  type, check out  [`skeleton` or `template`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#skeleton) in vim's `:help`

Comment: I supose only need to add when make a new file.
Then you can add this line to a vimrc file

`autocmd BufNewFile  *.html 0r ~/.config/vim/templates/skeleton.html `
BufNewFile execute when make a new file.
*.html  when file is *.html
0r insert in the begin the content of file template.html

Comment: You can add a abreviation with :ab or in then vimrc
Examples.
`:ab title <head><CR><title></title><CR></head>`
or inserting from template.
`ab  pyclass<esc>:r ~/.config/vim/templates/class.py`
when you write pyclass(return) insert file class.py.
<esc> exit from write mode
:r insert the content of file class.py
I have this line in my vimrc
`    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead  *.py  ab  pyclass<esc>:r ~/.config/vim/templates/class.py`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I do that by keeping under my vim folder a set of files which then I insert using the `r` command (which inserts the contents of a file, at the current location if no line number is passed) from some function:

```
function! Class()
    " ~/vim/cpp/new-class.txt is the path to the template file
    r~/vim/cpp/new-class.txt
endfunction
```

This is very practical - in my opinion - when you want to insert multi-line text. Then you can, for example, map a keyboard shortcut to call your function:

```
nmap ^N :call Class()<CR>
```

Comment: Can you think of a good cross-platform way to handle looking for the template files?  I like this idea but I'd love to us it on Windows, Linux, & OSX

Comment: OK, this is my favorite of all of them.  iab is nice but it's hard to set up for complicated file templates.  

A cross-platform way to handle paths would still be nice though.

Comment: For newbies like me: note that the file path is NOT a string; to use Class function arguments in the file path, [do like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103715/how-do-i-actually-use-the-value-of-an-argument-to-a-vim-function?lq=1) and use `exe 'r' . filepath`, where filepath is a string you can build however you want

Comment: @MarkBiek I'm pretty sure this *is* cross-platform. I use Vim on Windows, and it interprets `~` and `/` correctly. Using `~` instead of `/home/me` or `C:\User\me` is actually this function's saving grace, because Vim can figure it out.

Comment: The class doesn't seem to have a name. No?

Answer (score 44):

Late to the party, just for future reference, but another way of doing it is to create a command, e.g.

```
:command Inshtml :normal i your text here^V<ESC>
```

The you can call it as

```
:Inshtml
```

Explanation: the command runs in command mode, and you switch to normal mode with :normal, then to insert mode with 'i', what follows the 'i' is your text and you finish with escape, which is entered as character by entering ^V

It is also possible to add arguments, e.g.

```
:command -nargs=1 Inshtml :normal i You entered <args>^V<ESC>
```

where `<args>` (entered literally as is) will be replaced with the actual arguments, and you call it with

```
:Inshtml blah
```

Comment: Better to use `:normal!` to avoid any mapings you may have

Comment: will it be saved for always?

Answer (score 16):

i have created a new file **generate_html.vim** in **~/.vim/plugins/**
with the following code

```
"
" <This plugin generates html tags to new html files>
"

autocmd BufNewFile  *.html  call    Generate_html()

function! Generate_html()
    call append(0, "<!DOCTYPE HTML>")
    call append(1, "<html><head>")
    call append(2, "    <title></title>")
    call append(3, '    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />')
    call append(4, '    <style type="text/css">')
    call append(5, '    </style>')
    call append(6, '</head>')
    call append(7, '<body>')
    call append(8, '</body>')
    call append(9, '</html>')
endfunction
```

this way, everytime I open a new .html file in vim, it prints that text to the new file

Comment: This seems the only answer on how to do this as part of a Vim plugin. I realize all the other answers address the original problem but this is the only one that uses Vim Script and is the correct answer for anyone making a Vim Plugin.

Comment: Instead of using exact line number in `append` call you do `append("$", "some text")` to add line to the end of a buffer. It will allow to modify pre-defined text much easier.

Answer (score 8):

Can you define an abbreviation. e.g.

```
:ab insh 'your html here'
```

as nothing in the above appears to be parameterised ?

In fact, looking at my VIM configs, I detect a new .html file being loaded thus:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.html call GenerateHeader()
```

and define a function `GenerateHeader()` to insert my required template (I do the same for Java/Perl etc.).

It's worth getting the [Vim Cookbook](http://www.oualline.com/vim-cook.html) for this sort of stuff. It's a sound investment.

Answer (score 8):

### snippetsEmu

I like to use the [snippetsEmu](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1318) vim plugin to insert code snippets like your.

The advantage of snippetsEmu is that you can specify place holders and jump directly to them in order to insert a value. In your case you could for example add a place holder between the *title* tags so you can easily add a title to the document when inserting this snippet.

snippetsEmu comes with various snippets (also for HTML) and new snippets can be esaily added.

---

**EDIT**

### snipMate

Today I revisited my VIM confiugration + installed plugins and found the [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=254) plugin<strike>, which is IMHO even better than snippetsEmu</strike>. *snipMate* updates just like TextMate all placeholders on the fly.

Comment: I liked the sound of this plugin but I could never actually get it to work.

Comment: It looks like your link to snipMate is out of date? Or a typo? This looks like the right one: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540

Answer (score 4):

This should be possible. I use auto-replacement. In my .vimrc I have this line:

```
iab _perls #!/usr/bin/perl<CR><BS><CR>use strict;<CR>use warnings;<CR>
```

And whenever I start a Perl script, I just type _perls and hit Enter.

Comment: OK, ignore that comment.  I didn't understand that iab is the abbreviation command so you type _perls in insert mode.

Comment: I would have been nice if a specified the mode. You are absolutely correct.

Comment: This is definitely great for small stuff!

Comment: I'm using something similar, but the output is affected by `formatoptions` and other settings I haven't even discovered yet.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Python (or any other program) if like me you haven't quite grasped vimScript

[This guy](http://www.derekwyatt.org/vim/vim-tutorial-videos/vim-advanced-tutorial-videos/) talks about the vim expression register. Essentially you put something like this in your `.vimrc` file

```
:imap <C-j> <C-r>=system('/home/BennyHill/htmlScript.py')<CR>
```

So that every time in insert mode you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> it calls the script `htmlScript.py` which has something like this in it (**NOTE** I haven't actually tested this)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

snippet="""<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>"""

sys.stdout.write(snippet)
```

Then just remember to make the file executable (`chmod 0755 /home/BennyHill/htmlScript.py`). It might be overkill, but I am far more comfortable with Python than I am with vim's syntax.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I'll have to give that a look.

Comment: @MarkBiek It's much easier to use already established scripting languages, and it would be really simple to use mnemonic maps like `<C-j>html` or `<C-j>Cif`, `<C-j>Pyif`...

Comment: this works just fine but you forgot to chmod 755 /home/BennyHill/htmlScript.py and the first line should read #!/usr/bin/env python

Comment: @puk How to automate this process so that when I open a new python file it add these text?

Comment: @alhelal you should used `autocmd`. I am not very good at vim but this answer should point you in the direction https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11294

Answer (score 1):

You can once copy this text to some ( for example 'a' ) register. And paste it every time you need unless you overwrite register 'a'.

To copy to register a in visual mode: "ay
To paste from register a in normal mode: "ap
To paste from register a in insert mode: a

Or if you have this template already copied you can use

```
let @a = @*
```

To put this template to register a.

Answer (score 1):

There are many [template expander plugins](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion#Related_scripts) for vim.

NB: I'm maintaining the [fork of muTemplate](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/muTemplate). Just dump your code into 
`{rtp}/template/html.template` or into `$VIMTEMPLATES/html.template`. And that's all. If you don't want the snippet to be implicitly loaded when opening a new HTML file, then name the template-file `html/whatever.template` (instead of `html.template`), and load it with `:MuTemplate html/whatever` of with `whatever^r<tab>` in INSERT mode (in an HTML buffer).

All the path issues, portability issues, etc are already taken care of. And unlike snippetEmu that supports (and somehow expects) several ([hard to maintain](http://code.google.com/p/snippetsemu/source/browse/trunk/after/ftplugin/html_snippets.vim), IMO) snippets in a same snippets definition file, Mu-template requires one template-file per snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Put your text in a file (e.g.,`html`).
Then put the following in your `.vimrc`.
`command Inshtml r html`

I use `Inshtml` instead of `inshtml` because vim doesn't support user defined command starting with small letter.

Then if can type `Inshtml` in command mode (i.e., `:Inshtml`).