# help: multiline abbr in linux vi?

Tags: vim, vi, abbr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing a vim function to insert a block of static text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690386/writing-a-vim-function-to-insert-a-block-of-static-text)

How can i add multi line abbreviations in vi editor ?
I am using vi from ssh terminal.

if i type "head " the vi should replace "head" with  2 line sentence in the format 
as shown below

MAINTENANCE HISTORY
DATE           AUTHOR AND DETAILS

Thanks.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690386/writing-a-vim-function-to-insert-a-block-of-static-text?

Answer (score 0):

With vim you can do:

`:iab head MAINTENANCE HISTORY<CR>DATE AUTHOR AND DETAILS`

(Or use `imap`/`inoremap` instead of `iab` if you don't want to have to insert whitespace/punctuation before it activates)
No clue if this is possible in vi.

Comment: yes that will do. I was also looking to insert system date too. so far it is under the iab <expr> dts strftime("%d-%m-%y") & i need to type this separately. Is there any way to insert "# <system date> BAS TR-ORIGINAL" string as last line.

Comment: I think that would be OS-specific. On Unix-type systems and vim, try `iab head MAINTENANCE HISTORY<CR><C-R>=system("echo -n $(date)")<CR> BASTR-ORIGINAL`